# Merging 2 Images Using 2D Arrays as Pixels

Tags: java, arrays, image, merge, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to merge two B&W images based on the following parameters.

The new created array use the largest of the two image's width and height as it's own. The int at a specific point in the array contains a number which represents the gray scale amount. The new 2D array will merge the two images based on the following conditions.

- If the position exists in both arrays, the value in the results array is the average of the values in array a and b.
- if the position exists only in array a, the value in the results array is the value in array a
- if the position exists only in array b, the value in the results array is value in array b
- if the position is in neither array assign a value of 127 at that position in the results array.

Here is my code. It will not run as it returns an `arrayIndexOutOfBounds: 167` for some reason. I'd appreciate if someone could look it over.

```
public static int[][] merge(int[][] a, int[][] b)
{
    int biggerx = 0;
    int biggery = 0;
    if (a[0].length > b[0].length) {
        biggery = a[0].length;
    }
    else {
        biggery = b[0].length;
    }
    if (a.length > b.length) {
        biggerx = a.length;
    }
    else {
        biggerx = b.length;
    }
    int[][] merged = new int[biggerx][biggery];
    for (int x = 0; x < merged.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < merged[x].length; y++) {
            if (x <= a.length && y <= a[x].length && x > b.length && y > b[x].length) {
                merged[x][y] = a[x][y];
            }
            else if (x <= b.length && y <= b[x].length && x > a.length && y > a[x].length) {
                merged[x][y] = b[x][y];
            }
            else if (x <= b.length && y <= b[x].length && x <= a.length && y <= a[x].length) {
                merged[x][y] = ((a[x][y] + b[x][y]) /2);
            }
            else {
                merged[x][y] = 127;
            }
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (x <= b.length && y <= b[x].length && x <= a.length && y <= a[x].length) {
    merged[x][y] = ((a[x][y] + b[x][y]) /2); // <= problematic line
}
```

in this line you try to reach a point where it's out of a's bound. In my example, i set a to be `(10, 10)` and b to be `(5, 20)`. It crashed when `x = 0, y = 10`. Now, as you can see `a[0][10]` is out of bounds.

Here is my trial code and it's output:

```
else if (x <= b.length && y <= b[x].length && x <= a.length && y <= a[x].length) {
    System.out.println("x = " + x + " y = " + y);
    System.out.println("merged.length = " + merged.length);
    System.out.println("merged[0].length = " + merged[0].length);
    System.out.println("a.length = " + a.length);
    System.out.println("a[0].length = " + a[0].length);
    System.out.println("b.length = " + b.length);
    System.out.println("b[0].length = " + b[0].length);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    merged[x][y] = ((a[x][y] + b[x][y]) /2);
}
```

Output:

```
x = 0 y = 10

merged.length = 10

merged[0].length = 20

a.length = 10

a[0].length = 10

b.length = 5

b[0].length = 20
```

EDIT: Just noticed solution I proposed is not applicable for you.

EDIT2: `x <= a.length` and `y <= a[x].length` kind of statements needs to be changed into `x < a.length` and `y < a[x].length`  or `x <= a.length - 1` and `y <= a[x].length - 1`

Comment: if (x <= a.length-1 && y <= a[x].length-1 && x > b.length && y > b[x].length) {
                    merged[x][y] = a[x][y];
                }
                else if (x <= b.length-1 && y <= b[x].length-1 && x > a.length && y > a[x].length) {
                    merged[x][y] = b[x][y];
                }
                else if (x <= b.length-1 && y <= b[x].length-1 && x <= a.length-1 && y <= a[x].length-1) {
                    merged[x][y] = ((a[x][y] + b[x][y]) /2);
                }
                else {
                    merged[x][y] = 127;
                }

Comment: then, you need to revisit your if statements because they allow out of bound values for a and b.